# Unattended install of firefox extensions

Tags: installation, firefox, firefox-extensions

I'm building a "generic configuration script" for our ubuntu installations.

Coming to firefox there are some cool extensions I wish everyone to have (firebug, elasticfox-ec2tag and co...).

How can I have these extensions installed automatically into the firefox profile?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. Unaccepted answer or unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Flagged for deletion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See [this page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Installing_extensions), in particular:

> If you want to do a silent administrative install that immediately
>   makes the extension available to limited users, you need to uncompress
>   the `.xpi` file yourself (as a ZIP file) to an appropriately named
>   (extension's ID) folder. On Linux/Unix platforms you can use a helper
>   script to [determine extension
>   IDs](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Determine_extension_ID) in an automated
>   fashion.

Comment: Tried it and got very strange results. Some extensions managed to install but I had to confirm them in firefox. Some showed as disabled but I couldn't enabled them. And some just got ignored altogether. I think that the process outlined in the linked is outdated for the current version of firefox.